# Osmosis failed: ERROR: relation "pend_ways" does not exist

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, osmosis

I tried to generate osm update using osmosis and osmium(omsium only for setting configuration.txt from existing russia-latest.osm.pbf).

I use osmosis like that:

`osm2pgsql -append --slim --cache 10000 --proj 3857  --append -H  local -d osm -U osm_owner -W -P 5432  --input-reader xml -k change.osc`

There is reuslt:

```
Password:
Allocating memory for dense node cache
Allocating dense node cache in one big chunk
Allocating memory for sparse node cache
Sharing dense sparse
Node-cache: cache=10000MB, maxblocks=160000*65536, allocation method=11
Mid: pgsql, cache=10000
node cache: stored: 0(-nan%), storage efficiency: -nan% (dense blocks: 0, sparse nodes: 0), hit rate: -nan%
Osm2pgsql failed due to ERROR: PREPARE mark_ways_by_node(int8) AS select id from pend_ways WHERE nodes && ARRAY[$1];
PREPARE mark_ways_by_rel(int8) AS select id from pend_ways WHERE id IN (SELECT unnest(parts[way_off+1:rel_off]) FROM pend_rels WHERE id = $1);
 failed: ERROR:  relation "pend_ways" does not exist
LINE 1: PREPARE mark_ways_by_node(int8) AS select id from pend_ways .
```

my configuration.txt

```
baseUrl=http://download.geofabrik.de/russia-updates
maxInterval=60
```

my state.txt

```
#Thu Nov 21 16:44:37 MSK 2019
sequenceNumber=1473
timestamp=2019-11-20T21\:18\:03Z
```

What is this? It is a bag? I didn't find  `pend_ways` in osm2pgsql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had 2 critical mistakes in my osm2pgsql command:
will be `--append` instead `-append`
and I had to set `-r pbf` key, to allow detect pbf format